# Where do I download Android kernel source code (2.2 froyo)

Tags: android

I have downloaded Android source code (2.2 froyo) but it doesn't have the kernel source. Where do I download Android 2.2 froyo kernel source code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from where have you downloaded the froyo source code. plz send the link.

Comment: I downloaded the source very long time ago from the google repository which is currently down I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here :

> git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/kernel/common.git

Comment: The server is currently down..any other places please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct link to a .zip file of the Froyo sources
http://www.bigbluebrains.com/index.php/2010/08/08/browsing-android-2-2-froyo-source-code-in-eclipse/